# Applying View Options to Uploads

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, sorting

(First post here, so forgive me if I get anything wrong.)

I'm an artist, so I have a lot of image folders, and a lot of images *in* those folders. I order them by date to avoid confusion, but whenever I go to upload them, it defaults to ordering them alphabetically. This only happens when I upload the images, they're displayed in date order when I'm browsing them and alphabetical order when I'm prompted to upload an image.

How do I get the file explorer window for *uploading images* to listen to the order I have the folder actually *set* for? I don't know how to explain this any better than I am already, so tell me if it's confusing.

Comment: What application is displaying the upload selection dialog?

Comment: The file explorer, I think? This is something that happens every time I upload an image, no matter what I'm uploading it to.

Comment: When I hear "upload", I think "to internet". Are ypu perhaps talking about transferrinng images from a phone or camera to your computer?

Comment: Nope, any time I select an image to put *anywhere* on the internet, its ordered in a completely different way than what I've set my file explorer to. Sorry if my explanation was a little weird.

Answer (score 0):

Though they don't have the `View` ribbon, the Windows common dialogs have the same view options as **Explorer**. Right-clicking in the background displays the context menu:

[image]

Or change the view mode to `Details` and click a column header:

[image]

Like folder views, they should remember the view they were closed with.